# Positive Elements: Decomposition?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

**Problem**

Given a C*-algebra with unit $1\in\mathcal{A}$.

Then every selfadjoint element decomposes into positives ones:
$$A=A^*:\quad A=\frac12(|A|-A)-\frac12(|A|-A)\quad\left(\frac12(|A|\pm A)\geq0\right)$$

However, one also has the special dcomposition:
$$A=A^*:\quad A=\frac12(\|A\|1+A)-\frac12(\|A\|1-A)\quad\left(\frac12(\|A\|1\pm A)\geq0\right)$$

In general, they differ as $|A|\neq\|A\|1$. But the positive decomposition is unique, isn't it?

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant as summary. For more informations see:

- [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)
- [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762)

*(The second especially reveals the opinion of the community!)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing ingredient is orthogonality: $A_+A_-=A_-A_+=0$

The former ones are:
$$\frac12(|A|\pm A)\frac12(|A|\mp A)=\frac{1}{4}(|A|^2-A^2)=0$$
while the latter ones aren't:
$$\frac12(\|A\|1\pm A)\frac12(\|A\|1\pm A)=\frac12(\|A\|^21-A^2)\neq0$$
So only the first ones correspond to the unique decomposition!